# Weird str_replace output from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, str-replace

This is similar to one of my previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398418/intemperate-php-line-by-line), although this is looking for a solution rather than tools to debug it. I'm trying to build a script to (amongst other things) automatically replace names entered in a MySQL database with the name bolded in WikiMedia format, so when I enter NAME: I expect to get `'''NAME''':`. What I actually get is `NAME'''''':`. I've tried a sugestion posted on the aforementioned question to remove Carriage Returns from my array using `str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('', ''), $row);` but it had no effect.

The code I'm using to generate this is:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass);
$db = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
$query = "SELECT name FROM " . $prefix . ""; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $name[] = $row['name'];
}

$sim = $_POST['sim']; //Fetches SIM from text box.
$sim_wrap = wordwrap($sim, 80, "\n"); //Constrains to 80 columns for readability.
$sim_penultimate = str_replace("::", "<nowiki>::</nowiki>", $sim_wrap);

$sim_final = str_replace($row . ":", "'''" . $row . "''':", $sim_penultimate); //Bold     names
echo stripslashes($sim_final); //Removes slashes wordwrap() adds on some configurations example (James\'s).
?>
```

Thank you for any help you can give me, this really has me stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row` is a result from `mysql_fetch_array()` - in other words, it's an array. Why are you concatenating it with a string (`$row . ":"`)? Concatenating an array with a string doesn't work - you instead need to concatenate individual elements.

It seems like what you really want to do is something like this...

```
$names = array();
$replaces = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $names[] = $row['name'] . ":";
    $replaces[] = "'''" . $row['name'] . "''':";
}
```

and then later on...

```
$sim_final = str_replace($names, $replaces, $sim_penultimate); // Bold names
```

Comment: Good point... The values in the database don't have that identifier, but the text does... I could alter the database to have them...

Comment: See my edits. You don't need to alter your database entries at all (and you shouldn't).

Comment: Ok, the line now reads `$sim_final = str_replace($row, "'''" . $row . "'''", $sim_penultimate); //Bold names` but it doesn't do anything now... NAME: outputs as NAME:

Comment: Weird. It actually works perfectly, except for both of my test values!